# Inheritance AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a pycharm project with two .py files `signal.py` and `moving_average.py`.

`signal.py` looks something like:

```
class signal_class(object):

    long_short = 0
    underlying = ""
    def abc(self,...):
```

and `moving_average.py` looks something like:

```
import signal
import stock_wrapper
import pandas as pd
import signal

class SMA(signal.signal_class): #Error throws here.

    df = None
    s_w = None
```

Which looks correct to me but when I try to run I get the following error:

```
    class SMA(signal.signal_class):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'signal_class'
```

The error is thrown from the line market above.

I thought I followed the tutorial quite closely but I am unsure what is causing this.

Thank you very much for anyone who can help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has a builtin package named `signal`

- [Python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html)
- [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html)

So, when you do `import signal` that is being imported.

If you want to import your `signal_class` - either rename `signal.py` or do

```
from .signal import signal_class
```

and inherit `SMA` from there